# Signed right shift operator on negative operands

Tags: java

I'm reading Java spec. and here is written:

> The value of n >> s is n right-shifted s bit positions with
>   sign-extension. The resulting value is floor(n / 2s). For non-negative
>   values of n, this is equivalent to truncating integer division, as
>   computed by the integer division operator /, by two to the power s.

So if I have the following:

```
27 >> 3 // 00011011 >> 3 = 00000011 = 3 = 27/8
```

the result is `3`; in fact `27/8 = 3.375` and thus `3` is that value truncated.

But the spec say nothing when **left operand is negative**.

So if I have the following:

```
-50 >> 2 // 11001110 >> 2 = 11110011 = -13 != -50/4
```

the result is `-13`; but -`50/4 = -12.5` and thus `-13` is not that value truncated.

So what's the **rounding** system Java use when  the left operand is a negative value?

Maybe ***ceil(n / 2s)?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The resulting value is `floor(n / 2s)`.

*Floor* means round down: round towards negative infinity. This is not the same as truncation, i.e. removing the fractional part. Truncation would cause positive numbers to round down and negative numbers to round up.

The floor of -12.5 is -13.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/G3XX6Q)

Comment: But if your number is > n.5 then the result will be round up. Try with -77/8. Its result is -9.625 and the compiler returns -10!!! not -9!!!

Comment: @xdevel -10 is  lower than -9.625 so how is this rounded up?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking Java does not use a rounding system at all, it just shifts some bits. If you need `floor` or `ceil` then use `floor` or `ceil` and use bit-shift operators when you need them.